# How to get total number of rows, and latest row's value in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I have two tables named **Posts** and **Comments**.

Posts table looks like.

```
|id|user_id|content|created_at|updated_at|
|1 | 24    |demotxt|demo_date |demo_date |
|2 | 21    |domotxt|demo_date2|demo_date2|
|3 | 24    |domotxt|demo_date2|demo_date3|
|4 | 28    |dimotxt|demo_date3|demo_date5|
```

Comments table looks like

```
|id|user_id|post_id|comment |created_at|updated_at|
|1 | 24    |  3    |comment1|demo_date |demo_date |
|2 | 21    |  3    |xyadbsss|demo_date2|demo_date2|
|3 | 24    |  1    |okayokay|demo_date2|demo_date3|
|4 | 28    |  4    |somehtin|demo_date3|demo_date5|
```

What I am trying to achieve is to get **first latest comment** and total number of comments for each post. **i.e.**

```
|post_id|latest_comment |total_comments |
| 3     |xyadbsss       |2              |
| 1     |okayokay       |1              |
| 4     |somehtin       |1              |
```

This is the sql query I have tried

```
SELECT post_id, count(post_id) total_comments, comment latest_comment
FROM `comments` 
  LEFT JOIN posts on comments.post_id = posts.id
GROUP BY post_id;
```

Which is giving me

```
|post_id|latest_comment |total_comments |
| 3     |comment1[not latest]|2         |
| 1     |okayokay       |1              |
| 4     |somehtin       |1              |
```

Comment: use eloquent relationship + `withCount` to get a count of comments. use another `with('latestComment')` and define both relation on post model.

Comment: @BhaumikPandhi isn't there any other way. I mean I've used withCount but isn't there anyway I can manipulate the query to get latest comment also with count.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Also, do you have your models/relationships set up for `posts` and `comments`?

Comment: @Rwd I'm using Laravel 8 . Yes all the relationships are made for **Post** and **Comment** models

Comment: to get the count you need to group results which collapses multiple rows into one. Once this happens you lose all information about individual rows so the only way to do this would be via a subquery or by using ["windowing"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) which acts like grouping but does not collapse groups to a single row. I always found "GROUP BY" to be a very confusing name, I think calling it "AGGREGATE ON" would have cleared up a lot of confusion on it

Comment: Invalid GROUP BY, which is expected to raise an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to use the [latestOfMany](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-of-many) method. Add the following to your `Post` model:

```
public function latestComment()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Comment::class)->latestOfMany();
}
```

Then you can eager load the results:

```
$posts = Post::with('latestComment')->withCount('comments as total_comments')->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try something like this, not sure if is best solution.

```
SELECT 
c1.post_id,
count(c1.`post_id`) total_comments,
(
    SELECT 
        c2.comment
    FROM
        comments as c2
    WHERE
        c2.post_id = c1.`post_id`
    ORDER BY 
        c2.id DESC LIMIT 1
) as latest_comment
FROM 
`comments` as c1
GROUP BY 
c1.`post_id`;
```

I would rather loop the first data and do another query based on post id to get latest comment.

Comment: The comment is getting repeated.

Comment: hmm, can you retry i edited the query

Comment: Yes this is working fine, but it doesn't seem to be the optimized solution.

Comment: Nice, yea like i said not sure if is the best solution, i see a new guy commented how to use in laravel, so if you use laravel i suggest use his solution. Good Luck

Answer (score 2):

To get the latest record in database you can use this

```
Model::latest()->first();
```

So in your case to get the latest comment:

```
Comment::latest()->first()['comment'];
```

You can also use this method depending of your laravel version (if you use 5.7 or higher):

```
DB::table('comments')->latest('comment')->first();
```

Now to count all comments on a post you can looking for all comments with the post id and use the count property

```
$count = Comment::where('post_id',$the_id_of_the_post)->count();
```